# How to populate data in columns, each time 1 entry for a column, and loop on?

Tags: php, jquery, html, foreach, multiple-columns

i need populate a bunch of posts in a page where there are 3 columns:

column 1 |column 2|column 3 |

the result i want to get is:

column 1 |column 2|column 3 |
post1      post2    post3
post4      post5    post6

...

for example,
my html code looks like the following:

post1

post4

...

post2

post5

...

post3

post6

...

how can i do with PHP foreach?

i tried the  alternative way using jquery, first populate all the posts in the

, then add

to wrap every 3 posts, but that's not what i want..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a much detail to work with so my example makes a bunch of assumptions.  However, you should be able to adapt the php variables and desired html layout based on it:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
            <?php $i++; ?>
            <td><?php echo $post['title']; ?></td>
            <?php if($i == 3): ?> 
                </tr><tr>
                <?php $i = 0; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```